# VIM and viewport

Tags: vim, viewport

I have a simple question, I use Vim with two viewport:

1. e: (filesystem)
2. File editing

I would like to open the file I select from viewport one in viewport two, there is a way to tell that at Vim?

Comment: Whoever downvoted correct answers: that's not how SO works. you upvote helpful answers, downvote **incorrect** answers and all else is left untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use the really great [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugin. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-nerdtree-vim/).

Answer (score 0):

1) Execute `vim .` to open file browser viewport
2) Select a file to open with arrows and press `o`
It will open the file in a new window/viewport. (window size and another windows command you can see here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html)

Comment: Maybe my vim is full installed. I use this option every day. And thanks to someone for the -1. Really well-deserved. Maybe I should not open my mouth.

Comment: +1 for content, and I'd +1 to compensate for misguided downvote